# I am having problems with Cookies

Tags: javascript, html

The following HTML file is suppose to set a cookie and then the next time the file is loaded find the cookie. It works with the browser FireFox but not with Chrome. This was done on a Windows 10 machine.

A friend of mine tired it on his Mac for me and this is what he found:

Hit close, and in Chrome it came up again with no "username" in the text.  In Safari, the message was "getCookie called withusername=" some 4 5hex numbers separated by dashes "helpSession=914438-1284431863267".

Hit the close button, and it came up with a proper box to enter the name, and a "Cancel" clickable area followed by an OK clickable area, on the right of the bigger box.

Entered "test" and hit OK.  Chrome reported that it blocked the cookie. Safari reported an error, however the next time the 2nd message was "getCookie called withusername=test; helpSession=914438-1284431863267". The third OK gave "Welcome back test"

I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Bob

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    alert( "expires=" + expires );
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    alert( "getCookie called" + document.cookie );
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```